# Which incident connects Paramahansa Yogananda with Swami Vivekananda?

Tags: vivekananda

Swami Vivekananda I came to know had foretold that Paramhansa Swami Yogananda would come to USA for preaching hinduism.

Can anybody provide the source and details of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a disciple of Paramahansa Yogananda - Mr. Dickinson who had also met Swami Vivekananda and told about a prediction made by Swami Vivekananda which later came true through Paramahansa Yogananda.

Mr. Dickinson, a devotee of Paramhansa Yogananda recollects:

> “The beginning was dramatic: I was drowning. My older brother had playfully pushed me into a fifteen-foot pool in a small town in Nebraska. I was only five years old then. As I was about to sink for the second time under the water, a dazzling multicolored light appeared, filling all space. In the midst was the figure of a man with tranquil eyes and a reassuring smile. My body was sinking for the third time when one of my brother’s companions bent a tall slender willow tree in such a low dip that I could grasp it with my desperate fingers. The boys lifted me to the bank and successfully gave me first-aid treatment.

Autobiography of a Yogi / Chapter 47 - [I Return to the West](https://www.ananda.org/autobiography/#chap47):

> Twelve years later, a youth of seventeen, I visited Chicago with my mother. It was 1893; the great World Parliament of Religions was in session. **Mother and I were walking down a main street, when again I saw the mighty flash of light. A few paces away, strolling leisurely along, was the same man I had seen years before in vision.** He approached a large auditorium and vanished within the door. "Mother," I cried, "that was the man who appeared at the time I was drowning!" She and I hastened into the building; the man was seated on a lecture platform. **We soon learned that he was Swami Vivekananda of India.** After he had given a soul-stirring talk, I went forward to meet him. He smiled on me graciously, as though we were old friends. I was so young that I did not know how to give expression to my feelings, **but in my heart I was hoping that he would offer to be my teacher. He read my thought. "No, my son, I am not your guru."** Vivekananda gazed with his beautiful, piercing eyes deep into my own. **"Your teacher will come later. He will give you a silver cup." After a little pause, he added, smiling, "He will pour out to you more blessings than you are now able to hold."**

Swami Vivekananda had predicted that Mr. Dickinson's guru will come later and will give him silver cup. Seasons passed, months passed, years were passing rapidly and so was his conviction on what Swami Vivekananda had said but finally after 43 years of wait, Paramahansa Yogananda came and gave him a silver cup!

> Sometimes I wondered about the silver cup; I had almost persuaded myself that Vivekananda’s words were only metaphorical. But on Christmas night, as you handed me the square box by the tree, I saw, for the third time in my life, the same dazzling flash of light. In another minute I was gazing on my guru’s gift which Vivekananda had foreseen for me forty-three years earlier—a silver cup!

Comment: "Seasons passed, months passed, years were passing rapidly and so was his conviction" -- it gave me the impression that Im reading a novel or any other literary work